# What's the difference between UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum: and writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:?

Tags: ios

Both of these seem to be doing the same thing.

Is there are reason to use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UISaveVideoAtPath... is C API (a *function* defined in UIKit)

writeVideoAtPath... is Obj-C API (an *instance method* declared in ALAssetLibrary)